# how to go back to the previous 3rd screen in react native

Tags: react-native

So I have something like this,

1. Home->payment->sign up-> sign in
2. profile -> sign up -> sign in

I have alert function in sign in, when i click ok it should redirect me to profile or payment. Is there a way i can achieve this?

Comment: you want to goback without save the history ? I mean go into payment and can't navigate back to sign in with gesture or back button?

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz yes

Comment: So you have 2 stack or other screens also have Stack? Which version of react navigation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use pop in SignIn, pop accepts count optional parameter in your case for both cases the count is 2 so the code:

```
navigation.pop(2);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#pop